# Advantages of using spring security vs custom filters?

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, spring-security

This question might be naive but I would like to know what are the advantages of using Spring security (or any other security framework) versus custom filters (@WebFilter) to restrict pages in a web-app. In a custom filter I can check the session of an user, see if an user bean has been mapped within the session and then check if the user bean has the appropriate role to gain access to my restricted area. So what do I gain by using Spring security, surely it's more secure, if so then how? I'm asking because I find it harder to use than using custom filters. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security Principle: Don't roll your own security unless you're an expert.

See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own

The Spring guys aren't sitting around making work up for themselves. They are solving real problems. You could implement all of Spring Security's features with your filters, but then you'd have Spring Security, wouldn't you?

Are you handling CSRF and making it convenient?

Are you handling session fixation?

Do your filters handle path traversal?

Are you handling RunAs functionality?

Read the docs and decide if you should use it or not.